# i have uploaded an image to the server but it is not saved in the server

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a product table that has columns like manufactuer, category  product, etc.; like this:

```
manufacture name = stem ware
category name = simon pearce
product name = white flute ..
```

For this product its already has an image now I am uploading a new image to this  product, but the problem is the new image uploaded is not saved on the server.

I believe my code is correct, because it is only happening for this one particular product and not the rest of the products, anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        int fileSize1 = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        string filename1 = FileUpload1.FileName;

        //Checking the pic 1 Format
        if (CheckImageFormat(filename1.ToUpper()) == true) 
        {  
        }//Pic 1 Ends         

        item1 = txtitemNo.Text.Replace("/", "-");
        manufacturer1 = ddlMake_all.SelectedItem.Text;
        string subPath = "~/images/Products/" + manufacturer1;
        bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));
        if (!IsExists)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));
        }
        path1 = "~/images/Products/" + manufacturer1 + "/" + item1 + ".jpg";

        string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

        if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".gif" || fileExt==   ".png" || fileExt == ".JPEG" || fileExt == ".JPG" || fileExt == ".GIF")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path1));
        }
        else
        {
            lblnewmsg.Text = "Please upload Correct image";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you put a break point on `FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path1));` to see what `Server.MapPath(path1)` is resolving to?

Comment: Rather then using **~/** user **path1 = "images/Products/" + manufacturer1 + "/" + item1 + ".jpg";**